# Updated answer to old questions about getting values of one field

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there exists some new answers for an old post.

In particular, concerning Javascript, I am interested in the  following question:

[How to select a particular field from javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172277/how-to-select-a-particular-field-from-javascript-array)

that is, given a list of objects

```
var sample = [
[Name:"a",Age:1],
[Name:"b",Age:2],
[Name:"c",Age:3]
]
```

is there a way to get the list containing the values of the Name field of all the elements of sample without using any loop structure.

I would hope data science would have answered this question.

Comment: You cannot traverse through an array without a loop. If the array is fixed then you can get values by index. Otherwise you have to loop through it.

Comment: Nope, you still have to loop. :-) (Unless, of course, you know in advance what specific entries you want, as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7172340/157247) notes.) Even if there were an API call that did the loop for you, it would still be a loop. Modern syntax helps slightly via destructuring (just in case none of the answers addresses it): `const names = theArray.map(({name})) => name);`

Comment: ok I am good with it T.J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `map()`

```js
let sample = [
  {Name: "a", Age: 1},
  {Name: "b", Age: 2},
  {Name: "c", Age: 3}
]

let res = sample.map(el => el.Name)
console.log(res)
```